# Why rails + elasticsearch don't hit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, search, elasticsearch

Today I started to read about elasticsearch and I'm trying to use it in my ruby on rails application.

So I did some adjusts like I see in example:

https://raw.github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails/master/elasticsearch-rails/lib/rails/templates/01-basic.rb

My Model:

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks
end
```

My controller:

```
class ServicesController < ApplicationController
  (...)  
  # GET /services/search
  def search
    @services = Service.search(params[:q]).records
    render action: "index"
  end
  (...)
end
```

My view:

```
(...)
<%= form_tag search_services_path, method: 'get' do %>
<%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q] %>
<%= button_tag :search %>
<% end %>
(...)
```

My routes:

```
Newapp::Application.routes.draw do
  (...)
  resources :services do
    collection { get :search }
  end
  (...)
end
```

But when I find for anything I always receive 0 (zero) results.

Other think that I tried to do:

```
$ curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/services/_search?pretty' -d '
 { "query": { "match_all": {} } }'
```

It returns:

```
{
  "took" : 2396,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

What I need to do to elasticsearch find data saved in my data base through my rails model

Thanks for help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article was enough to solve all my doubts.

http://www.sitepoint.com/full-text-search-rails-elasticsearch/

My problem was solved adding:

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'
```

In the top of my Model, and adding:

```
Article.import # for auto sync model with elastic search
```

In the bottom of my Model.